# DeprecationWarning: `h2o.gbm` is deprecated. Use the estimators sub module to build an H2OGradientBoostedEstimator

Tags: python, h2o, gbm

When running a gbm model using h2o 3.6.0.8 in Python I get the following warning:

> DeprecationWarning: `h2o.gbm` is deprecated. Use the estimators sub module to build an H2OGradientBoostedEstimator.

I have been looking for an example on how to build a H2OGradientBoostedEstimator but with no success. Could you please direct to the right path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are examples in the [H2O GBM Vignette](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-docs/src/booklets/v2_2015/PDFs/online/GBM_Vignette.pdf).

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I needed